# android studio git, deleting and renaming another file to the deleted file's name

Tags: git, android-studio, delete-file

I use Android studio with its default GIT (local)

I have performed a big refactoring of my code: I had classes like this:

```
Layer_Image.java
Layer_Image_v2.java
Layer_Image_v3.java
Layer_Image_v4.java
Layer_Image_v5.java
```

I deleted all but the last one (v5) and renamed it to `Layer_Image.java.`. I did these operations from Android Studio project window.

Now when I try to commit the project, Git complains that `Layer_Image.java` already exists so it can't add the `Layer_image_v5` renaming it to Layer_Image ("aliasing" as the message says). This is the message I get:

**Commit failed with error: Will not add file alias. Layer_Image already exists in index**

I guess my fault was not committing the deletion of `Layer_Image.java` before renaming `Layer_Image_v5`: I did it all at once and just tried to commit at the end.

Can I easily fix this from Android Studio UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rename Imagev5 Imagev6 and do a commit as that will not only register you deletes with git but also prepare you for the next step..

The next step after that git commit is rename imagev6 to Image..and git will accept it.

Comment: yeah sometimes just the simple core of problem is what solves it